# Cancel /Kill http api call angular 2

Tags: api, http, angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

Sometimes `http` api call takes long time to load data. In this case, if we move on another component, it still keeps executing (we can see it in browser console). So, is there any way by which we can cancel or kill `http` api call when we move on another component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "kill" it by using `unsubscribe()` method in `OnDestroy` lifecycle event, under assumption you are using subscriptions, for example:

```
mySubscription: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.mySubscription = this.myHttpCall().subscribe...
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you... :) By using this, I can `unsubscribe()` one api but is there any way by which i can `unsubscribe()` multiple apis by using just one variable.

Comment: You can use the takeWhile() function from rxjs to unsubscribe all the subscriptions: Example:

http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `takeWhile()` function from rxjs to unsubscribe all the subscriptions: Example:

http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/